# Cisco Jabber 9.7.2 doesn't integrate with Outlook 2013 calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, cisco-jabber

I have both these as my IM and mail clients at work, respectively. Cisco Jabber has a tab that's supposed to show calendar appointments from Outlook, and auto-change status when you're in a meeting. When I switch to that tab, all I see are instructions on how to enable it from the options (which I've already done under File>Options>Integration).

I read that Lync 2013 may interfere with this, so I've disabled the Lync add-in in Outlook, and confirmed that the Lync process isn't running in the background. Despite restarting both, as well as Windows 7 itself, it doesn't integrate and continues to show me the enablement message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a registry fix.
Save the following as a `.reg` file and merge it with your registry, then restart Outlook & Jabber. After that, the calendar entries show up in the meetings tab of Jabber, and it switches your status to 'Meeting' if there is one scheduled in Outlook.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem]
"MAPI"="1"
"MAPIX"="1"
"MAPIXVER"="1.0.0.1"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem]
"MAPI"="1"
"MAPIX"="1"
"MAPIXVER"="1.0.0.1"
```

Also note that at the time of posting this fix, the latest version of Jabber is `10.6.4`, so might be a good idea to upgrade to the latest first.

Comment: testing version 11 at this moment;)

Comment: Oh well, they only deployed 10.6.4 in my organization :)
When I check for update, it says I'm using the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I have a recent version of Jabber and the integration options are provided in Calendar tab of Options. I tried setting to MS Outlook and None and both options work as expected.

[image]

Comment: Set it to Outlook and import the registry shared by Rex

Comment: He was saying it already works for him.